# A Queue is a collection for holding elements prior to processing

Tags: collections, queue

A Queue is a collection for holding elements prior to processing. All the collection needs some data before processing. Then why only in the queue interface it is mentioned like this..?. ArrayList, Linked List all required needs to insert data before processing the collection. Can any one help me on this

Answer (score 0):

I think its dependent upon the requirement how the data should be processed.

Let's say you have a queue in cinema for buying tickets, now the tickets should be allocated to a person in the order they have come, so in this case QUEUE is preferred data structure as it maintains the FIFO(First In First Out) order.

But, in some other scenario, you might want data to be processed in order of "priority", in that case QUEUE might not come handy, you would want some *sorting mechanism* on priority on the data structure before processing it.<>
So, there are different data structures which keeps different way of handling data based on requirement.

You can search on different data structure and their processing, data storage for finding which best suits the need

Comment: But in the documentation it is mentioned that the Queue must have data prior to processing. What i mean is all the collection should have data to process. Then why it is mentioned only in the Queue that "A Queue is a collection for holding elements prior to processing".

Answer (score 0):

*A queue is a waiting line.* It was added to the JCF with Java 5.0. **And Reflecting the print queue prototyping, the Java doc states this** - a Queue is a collection for holding elements prior to processing.

Answer (score 0):

Think that there are two states for an element of the queue, "on hold(OH)" and "ready for processing(RFP)". Now, the head of the queue have the RFP state and all other elements have the OH state. Concluding, queue holds it's OH-elements prior they become RFP-element (head). After an element become RFP it can be popped out and processed.